# .htaccess rewrite isn't working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that has five different types of querys:

```
example.com/?page=homeoranyotherpage
example.com/?page=portfolio&pageid=3
example.com/?page=admin
example.com/?page=admin&pageid=portfolio
example.com/?page=admin&pageid=portfolio&itemid=3
```

I have tried to get this to show in this way using .htaccess:

```
example.com/home
example.com/portfolio/3
example.com/admin
example.com/admin/portfolio
example.com/admin/portfolio/3
```

Here is the .htacces:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index\.php?page=$1 - [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\$ /?page=$1&pageid=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?page=$1&pageid=$2&itemid=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Any ideas on how to make this actually work? I also have the filename requests in order to still make it to where it allows me to have my CSS and Javascript still load.

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the _path_ component of the requested URL only, so `^index\.php?page=$1` will never match. If you need to check on query string contents, you need to do so with a RewriteCond preceeding the RewriteRule.

Comment: But I don’t think you should need this check at all here. Once the request has been rewritten to the index.php internally, the existing conditions should catch that this request now matches an existing file, on the next iteration. (Not sure if that works if you rewrite to just `/?page=…` though, I’d try and explicitly use `/index.php?page=…` in those places.)